# What does console.log.bind(console); do?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have this in an application I am working on:

```
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError',
        function (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) {
            console.log.bind(console);
        });
```

Can someone give me advice on what it does? I have no idea why it was added but now I am looking at it and think I should at least know what it does.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case it does absolutely nothing of value. I'd think some refactoring went wrong, and what it was actually supposed to do was this:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', console.log.bind(console));
```

This attaches the `console.log` method as event handler, which will simply cause it to log every invocation of the event. Due to the way `this` is bound at calltime, `.bind(console)` is necessary to preserve the context correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It does nothing, at least not anything useful ...

Sometimes you might see something like:

```
z = x.y.bind(x)
```

In this case, `z` is a function that executes the function `x.y` with the `this` argument set to `x`.  In your case, since the return value of `bind` is never used, the statement is just creating a function that never gets used.  You'll also see this frequently passed to callbacks.  As a stupid example:

```
var foo = function(a, callback) {
    callback(a);
};

foo(a, b.c.bind(b));
```

This is the same thing as calling `b.c(a)`